# Getting Error on GeoServer :Error obtaining new data store and Exception

Tags: geoserver, geotools

Here is i added GeoServer Log

**WARN [data.store] - Error obtaining new data store**

**Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9090/mapd"**
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
        at com.mapd.jdbc.MapDConnection.(MapDConnection.java:80)
        at com.mapd.jdbc.MapDDriver.connect(MapDDriver.java:52)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.geotools.data.jdbc.datasource.AbstractManageableDataSource.getConnection(AbstractManageableDataSource.java:48)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2081)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createTypeNames(JDBCDataStore.java:992)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getTypeNames(ContentDataStore.java:308)
        at org.vfny.geoserver.util.DataStoreUtils.getDataAccess(DataStoreUtils.java:97)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getDataStore(ResourcePool.java:638)
        ... 119 more

so how to solve this error and Exception?

Comment: For this kind of open ended questions you're using the wrong medium, better ask on the geotools-users or geotools-devel mailing lists.